# Can't include custom jQuery scripts into my wp theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I was trying for a while to include my jQuery scripts (one plugin, one self written) into my custom wordpress theme. Despite of reading a lot about how to include them properly I somehow can't manage to get it working. 
So I have one plugin script (**jQuery.fullPage.js**) and a custom written (**main.js**) which are (**both!**) placed in the "**assets/scripts/**" directory.

As described in the instructions I register them in the **functions.php**:

```
   function load_theme_scripts() {
          wp_register_style('fullPageStyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom-css/jquery.fullPage.css');
          wp_enqueue_style( 'fullPageStyle');
          wp_register_script( 'theFullPage', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/jquery.fullPage.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
          wp_enqueue_script( 'theFullPage');
          wp_register_script( 'mainScript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/main.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
          wp_enqueue_script( 'mainScript');
   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_theme_scripts' );`
```

Having only this code nothing happened at all. After some reading I figured out (don't know if it's the right way) that I have to call the scripts as well in the `<head>` of html code.
So in the `<head>`of my **home.html** I now have the following code:

```html
<head>
<title><?php wp_title()?></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/portfolio_wordpress/wp-content/themes/myportfolio/assets/scripts/jquery.fullPage.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/portfolio_wordpress/wp-content/themes/myportfolio/assets/scripts/main.js'></script>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Now the scripts are called (Please correct me if sth. not according to the best practice!) but I get the error: `Can't find variable: $` in my **main.js**. I thought probably that's because of the compatibility mode of jQuery in wordpress so replace the `$`with `jQuery`but then the error is `Can't find variable: jQuery`.

The **main.js** code with the `$`:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("Main script is workin!");
      $('#fullpage').fullpage({
          scrollingSpeed: 1000
      });
      alert("Main script is workin!");
   });
```

The **main.js** with the `jQuery`instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    alert("Main script is workin!");
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        scrollingSpeed: 1000
    });
    alert("Main script is workin!");
});
```

Please help me with that it's really driving me crazy! Since Im new to writing custom themes for wp tips for coding this functionality in a better or cleaner way are very welcome!

Comment: get_template_directory_uri() gets from template folder . and   plugins_url( '/js/custom-script.js', __FILE__ )  from plugin folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution found!**

So I figured out what the problem was! Actually sth really dumb.
To load jQuery the `<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>`has to be called **before** the `<?php wp_head(); ?>`. All custom scripts e.g. main.js have to be called like this:
 `<script type='text/javascript' src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/assets/scripts/main.js"></script>` **after** the `<?php wp_head(); ?>`function.

So now my total `<head>`of the html looks like this:

```
<head>
<title><?php wp_title()?></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<script type='text/javascript' src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/assets/scripts/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/assets/scripts/main.js"></script>
```

The post from https://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/ by Chris Coyier helped me with this problem a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It just and example

## How to add scripts from template and plugin.

```
function wptuts_scripts_important()
{
    // Register the script like this for a plugin:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom-script.js', __FILE__ ) );
    // or
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-script.js' );
 
    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_important', 5 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I should move jQuery.fullPage.js plugin in a separate folder!

Answer (score 0):

If that js located into plugin folder then you need to used plugin_url() path instead of get_template_directory_uri().Becuase template directory function used for the located path of an activated theme.
I hope it's helpful to you.
For Example:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_plugin_scripts');
function load_plugin_scripts(){ 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'plugin_custom_lm_js', plugins_url( 'assets/scripts/jquery.fullPage.js', __FILE__ ) );
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the description at the beginning. Both scripts are in the theme directory in /assets/scripts/ !